# re-open modal after close retains values

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the something similar to the following modal but if I enter values and then press cancel button and then re-open it, the Treated Area value does not reset. Note, in this sample it is working perfectly but in real application (with other working elements it somehow does not reset on open dialog. However, after I press a tab or enter some value it does update then.

I have tried reproducing the code but the code below works perfectly as expected.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap Example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function(){
$(this).hide();
 });
});
function calculateQtyAndCost(){
var treatPerc = $('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatPerct').val();

if (treatPerc != '') {

    var projectCaseId = 642;
        
            var treatedArea = parseFloat(3500 * treatPerc / 100);
            //treatment area percentage calculation
            $('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatArea').val(treatedArea);
    }
    else {
    $('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatArea').val(0);
 }
 console.log($('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatArea').val());
 }

function OpenEditProjectCaseMaintenanceConstructionEquipmentHours(){
$('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatPerct').val('');
    //$('#selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatArea').val('');
    calculateQtyAndCost();
    
  $('#edit-pavement-maintenance-removal-process-dialog').modal({ backdrop: 'static' }, 'show');

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="modal" id="edit-pavement-maintenance-removal-process-dialog" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 440px">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span id="spnEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTitle"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="" id="edit-pavement-maintenance-removal-process-dialog-form" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                <div class="row">
                <p><b>Total Area: 3500m²</b></p>

 <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Treatment Area:</label> <span style="margin-left: 5px" class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title='Treatment area percentage'></span>
                            <div class="input-group suffix">
                                <input id="selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatPerct" class="clsDec2 form-control" type="text" required onblur="calculateQtyAndCost();"/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon suffix"> %</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--start of new code-->
                    <div class="col-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Treated Area:</label> <span style="margin-left: 5px" class="fa fa-info-circle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title='Area to be worked on is calculated based on the percentage in Treatment Area'></span>
                            <div class="input-group suffix">
                                <input id="selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessTreatArea" class="clsInt form-control" type="text" disabled/>
                                <span class="input-group-addon suffix"> m²</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div>
                                <div class="float-left">
                                    <label for="selEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessType">Attribute Removal Process:</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="float-right">
                                    <a href="#" onclick="OpenEditRemovalProcess(-1); return false"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Custom Process</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <p id="pEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessType" style="margin: 10px 0"></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                          
                  
                     
                </div>
                <div id="divEditProjectCaseMaintenanceRemovalProcessError" class="clsDialogError" style="color: #F00"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="margin: 20px 0 0 10px; font-size: 20px">
                                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-ok" onclick="OpenEditProjectCaseMaintenanceConstructionEquipmentHours()"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Construction Equipment Hours</button>
                                        </div>
                                        

</body>
</html>
```

The actual sample looks as follows after re-open :

[image]

Comment: while opening the model you are calling `calculateQtyAndCost` which enters the value in a modal form corresponding field. In case you don't want then remove the method call.

Comment: Under OpenEditProjectCaseMaintenanceConstructionEquipmentHours I have tried commenting calculateQtyAndCost and uncommenting the line above, console.log shows val is '' but does not happen on ui-until I press tab